# carousel div in bootstrap

Tags: jquery, carousel

I am having problem with carousel Bootstrap.

[image]

I want it display like that, but I can not find the solution.

Could anyone help me?

Comment: try this http://codepen.io/danbhala/pen/eNZrQW

Comment: I have seen it but how i prevent from auto play slide? I want user click not auto like that

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:**  for auto play add class `slide` into `<div id="carousel-example-vertical" class="carousel vertical ">`
or for manual click change remove `slide` from  `<div id="carousel-example-vertical" class="carousel vertical slide">` tag

**[demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/OMVYqm)**